# How to remove this mysqli warning?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am doing an update in my php/mysqli. The update works fine but the problem I have is that I keep getting this warning:

Warning: mysqli_stmt::fetch() [mysqli-stmt.fetch]: (HY000/2053): Attempt to read a row while there is no result set associated with the statement in on line 44.

Because I keep getting this warning, it means that after the user submits the form, even with the correct username typed it, it still displays the message "The Username you Entered is not Valid. Try Entering it Again." when really it should navigate the user to the thankyou.php page.

So my question is how do I remove this warning?

```
 $username = (isset($_POST['username'])) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
      $newpassword = (isset($_POST['newpassword'])) ? $_POST['newpassword'] : '';
      $loggedIn = false;

      if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        // don't use $mysqli->prepare here
        $query = "UPDATE Teacher SET TeacherSalt = ?, TeacherPassword = SHA1(CONCAT(?,?)) WHERE TeacherUsername = ? LIMIT 1";
        // prepare query
        $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
        // You only need to call bind_param once
        $stmt->bind_param("ssss",$salt,$newpassword,$salt,$username);
        // execute query
//bind results
$stmt->bind_result($dbTeacherUsername,$dbTeacherPassword,$dbTeacherSalt);
        $stmt->execute(); 

        while($stmt->fetch()) {
          if ($username == $dbTeacherUsername) {
            $loggedIn = true;
          }
        }

        /* close statement */
        $stmt->close();

        /* close connection */
        $mysqli->close();

        if ($loggedIn == true){
          $_SESSION['username'] = $dbTeacherUsername;
          header( 'Location: thankyou.php' ) ;
          die();
        }
      }
     if ($loggedIn == false && $_POST) {
        echo "The Username you Entered is not Valid. Try Entering it Again.";
        }
      ?>
```

Comment: Calling **fetch** for update query?

Comment: @Dr.Dan What I did was use the same template I had made for a previous Select statement and just changed the select statement with the update statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$stmt->execute(); 

        while($stmt->fetch()) {
          if ($username == $dbTeacherUsername) {
            $loggedIn = true;
          }
        }
```

to

```
    if($stmt->execute()) {
      if ($username == $dbTeacherUsername) {
        $loggedIn = true;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, If I change it to what you have stated, I now get this notice: `Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result() [mysqli-stmt.bind-result]: Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in ... on line 40`

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE` statements don't yield a result set. Quoting from [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php):

> If the statement is ***UPDATE***, ***DELETE***, or ***INSERT***, the total number of affected rows can be determined by using the `mysqli_stmt_affected_rows()` function. Likewise, if the query yields a result set the `mysqli_stmt_fetch()` function is used.

Comment: Do I need a bid_result with an UPDATE?

Answer (score -1):

You've possibility to remove "Warning Info" in PHP , you just replace, in your php.ini

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

by

```
error_reporting  =  0
```

But Warning Infos don't appear if your code is perfect, the must for don't appear Warning in Php, is to **resolve** the **warning message problem**.

in your code, you have a problem just before line 44. Look at with your "While Loop"...

**Edit**: I juste read your answer + 1 Dr. Dan

Answer (score -3):

You can remove any warning on PHP by either changing the error_reporting() function at the top of the script. Put:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_WARNING ^ E_NOTICE);
```

That's all errors, except warnings or notices. Alternatively, if it's just one function, you can prefix the function call with an at sign:

```
while (@$stmt->fetch()) {
    //do stuff
}
```

For example.

Comment: Suppressing warnings and errors is rarely the correct way to deal with them.